# Fish shell new function : "ssh: command not found "

Tags: ssh, fish

I'm trying to create a function that connects me to a ssh server then become su, and then ssh into another server so I did the following:

```
function test 
     ssh -t testuser@server1 'sudo ssh -t testuser@server2' 
end
```

When I execute it I get the following error `ssh: command not found`

But when I execute it straight to the terminal it works with no problems.

Comment: Don't call a function `test`. That's the name of a rather important fish builtin. In the upcoming 3.0, that name is reserved.

Comment: @faho I used function test in this case, but my function is called something else.

Comment: Perhaps the error is coming from server1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved when I added each one of them to the fish functions folder:

~/.config/fish/functions

I just created a file called myfunction.fish and inside of that file I pasted the function definition:

```
function myfunction 
     ssh -t testuser@server1 'sudo ssh -t testuser@server2' 
end
```

saved it, exited fish and now that function is permanent.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a path issue on server1.

From the command line, what do you see if you type the following?

```
ssh -t testuser@server1 sudo which ssh
```

If SSH is not in the path for root, you might need to specify full paths, such as something like:

```
ssh -t testuser@server1 sudo /usr/bin/ssh testuser@server2
```

You may need to adjust the paths to match your environment, of course.

Also, if you're trying to connect from root at server1 to server2, can you just ssh directly to root@server1? If so, you could perhaps use the "ProxyJump" functionality that was added with OpenSSH 7.3. This depends upon the ability to remotely login as root, which may not be an option, depending on your environment.

```
ssh -J root@server1 testuser@server2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it works great on bash so the path is right, it's just that for some reason fish doesn't like it.

Comment: But is fish getting the same path as bash? And when you say it "works great on bash," are you running fish on any of the remote servers?

Comment: I'm not running them on the remote servers. I only have fish installed on my client box.